# Only some images are not displaying in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I am having an odd issue with certain images not displaying in Firefox, but displaying in every other browser.

[You can see the differences between Chrome and Firefox here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3LgH.jpg)

I am using an unordered list to display a row of images that are list items. However, at the beginning of each row, I am placing a normal image in the list that is not tagged as a list item. **This works perfectly in Chrome, Edge, IE and Safari but, for some reason, only a few of those images won't display in Firefox.** What is confusing is that there is nothing fundamentally different about rows one and two when compared to rows three and four - that I see anyway.

**It is also squishing the images in row three and four and I'm not having that issue in other browsers**.

The only differences I can see are image URLs. I tried removing the disable divider to see if that made a difference and it did not.

**I have created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75hth4eg/) to replicate the issue.**

What is included below is a greatly reduced version of what you will find using the link.

```css
  hr {
  opacity: .5;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-style: inset;
  background: #00adbd;
  border-top: 0.5px dotted #fff;
}

.disabledbutton {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#outeroutside {
  background-image: url("/assets/tile.jpg");
  background-color: #a00f14;
  width: 1300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#outside {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(252, 251, 245, 0.95);
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#welcomemain p {
  width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  height: auto;
}

#welcomemain img {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  color: #2e1f11;
}

#outeroutside a:link {
  color: #996515;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#outeroutside a:hover {
  color: #FFD700;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#outeroutside a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #996515;
}

#outeroutside a:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.row2 a {
  color: #C0C0C0 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.row2 a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #999999;
}

.row2 a:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#navigation img {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.youtube {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60%; // This is the aspect ratio
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.youtube iframe {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

b {
  color: #312112;
}

i {
  color: #b05830;
}

.font {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .spinner {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 10px groove #fdec6d;
  border-right-color: #739968;
  border-bottom-color: #739968;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img:before {
  display: none;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1.colored .info {
  background: #1a4a72;
  background: rgba(26, 74, 114, 0.6);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #333333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px white, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info p {
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .spinner {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ih-item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item,
.ih-item * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ih-item a {
  color: #333;
}

.ih-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ih-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ih-item.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ih-item.circle .img {
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ih-item.circle .img:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle .img img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ih-item.circle .info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .spinner {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 10px solid #ecab18;
  border-right-color: #1ad280;
  border-bottom-color: #1ad280;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img:before {
  display: none;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1.colored .info {
  background: #1a4a72;
  background: rgba(26, 74, 114, 0.6)
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info p {
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 11px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .spinner {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px 3px 30px 3px;
  width: 1115px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nonwrap;
  align-content: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: rgba(238, 155, 195, 0.95);
}

.row2 {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px 3px 15px 3px;
  width: 1115px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nonwrap;
  align-content: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: rgba(238, 46, 54, 0.95);
}

.col-sm-6 li {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  max-width: 33.3%;
}

a.effect-shine:hover {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 30%, #000 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 70%);
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
  animation: shine 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 150%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: -50%;
  }
```

```html
    <ul id="week1">
            <ul class="row">

              <img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Scroll_Week1.1.png">




              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Gator_Buckles.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>$5 Gator Buckle Sets</h3>
                        <p>Get a selection of 6-piece gator buckle sets for just $5. These opulent adornments are jewel encrusted and waiting to make your belt fancy!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/5-gator-buckle-sets" class="effect-shine">Click here to see all styles! </a></p>
              </li>
              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Liz_CraftPack.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Liz's Craft Pack</h3>
                        <p>Explore the possibilities of leather craft with Liz's craft pack. Bursting at the seams with leather components, this not-so-little pack is only $25!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>

                  <P> <a href="/Lizs-Craft-Pack" class="effect-shine">Get Liz's Craft Pack Here!</a></p>
              </li>
              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Stamping_Tools.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>25% Off Stamping Tools</h3>
                        <p>Transform your veg tan with stamping tools! For this month only, get select stamping tools at an even lower price! Nearly 100 tools are included!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/tools/Tools-Specials-Closeouts-Deals/SALE-Stamping-Tools" class="effect-shine">Click here to view the selection!</a></p>
              </li>

              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_BeltBend_Black.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Black Belt Bends</h3>
                        <p>These Hermann Oak drum dyed belt bends are magnificent and they're on sale! Get them in black or brown. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/Hermann-Oak-Belt-Bend-Black" class="effect-shine">Get Black Hermann Oak Belt Bend Here!</a></p>
              </li>

              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_BeltBend_Brown.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Brown Belt Bends</h3>
                        <p>These Hermann Oak drum dyed belt bends are magnificent and they're on sale! Get them in black or brown.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/Hermann-Oak-Belt-Bend-Brown" class="effect-shine">Get Brown Hermann Oak Belt Bend Here!</a></p>
              </li>


              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_VegTan_Split_Bundle.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Veg Tan Split Bundle</h3>
                        <p>Our new splitter has left us swimming in veg tan splits! Get this sweet bundle for just $15!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="target.html" class="effect-shine">Get Your Veg Tan Split Bundle Here!</a></p>
              </li>
              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Jr_LegalPad_Templete.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Legal Pad Poly Template</h3>
                        <p>We have finally done it! Poly templates for one of our favorite projects: leather covers! Cover your legal pad in luxury with this template for only $5.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/Polymer-Templates-Junior-Legal-Pad-Cover" class="effect-shine">Get Your Legal Pad Template Here!</a></p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>

          <hr>
```

Please note: This code has a number of problems in IE due to lack of support for some features, however even IE is displaying the leading image in each row. There are small circles in the li's that appear in the JS Fiddle that do not display on my actual website.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/75hth4eg/

Comment: @Marios Did you make a change to the code? I'm not seeing anything different.

Comment: no i will copy your code to test it

Comment: This is invalid HTML.  The only acceptable child element of a `ul` element is an `li` element.  Here you have an `img` as a child of a `ul`.

Comment: If you start setting the `<li>` elements to `display:none`, you'll see that the ticket comes back. It's something to do with how FF handles flexbox and invalid (?) elements....as @JosephMarikle says, it is invalid HTML -- so why not wrap the `<img>` in an `<li>`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's correct, but this is still possible to show this image in FF by setting the width of the image in css.

Comment: http://springfiedleather.com/assets/Week2_Shoulder_Black.jpg it cannot be found

Comment: http://springfiedleather.com/assets/Week2_Shoulder_Black.jpg In my firefox and chrome it cannot display image because it cannot be found.Your HTML code is incorrect, you should fix it as it's stated below

Comment: @MariosNikolaou yes, that URL was entered incorrectly, but this is not the image I am having trouble with. In the original code "springfieldleather.com" is not present in links so that wouldn't be contributing to the issue.

Comment: @user1370384 & everyone else - thank you for your input. I originally planned to wrap the image in an li, but wanted the first image to look different. I placed a normal image as a placeholder and it seemed to do everything I wanted it to without having to add any additional CSS. Wrapping it in an li would have worked though! Still, I will keep all of this in mind. This has been helpful.

Comment: @RauliRajande I'm interested in what you mean by setting the width of the image in CSS. The images have a max-width set in #welcomemain img. Are you suggesting that if the width were specified differently it could also be a fix?

Comment: @ChaniquaCrook max-width means that the width can still be 0. This doesn't make them have any real width. If you force width with 'min-width: 100px; ' for example, then FF starts showing these images.

Comment: @RauliRajande ah gotcha! So adding dimensions in-line like I did with the tickets at the top would also fix my problem. I am assuming that the same would apply to using percentages as well then. Thank you!

Comment: @ChaniquaCrook Yes, as a quick fix. In long run try to refactor your template not to include the image as ul child. I would change ul and li tags to divs, to make things easier and get rid of their default properties.

Comment: @RauliRajande That is a good suggestion. Hopefully next time I do something like this, I will have less elements to add. I was worried about making a mess of closing tags with too many DIVs, especially since I am working with even less experienced people. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to fix your markup.  As pointed out in my comment, you have invalid HTML.  Regardless, to correct the display issue in FF, here is a possible solution:

Flexbox is shrinking your img.  You can configure it not to.  I've added `flex-shrink: 0` to `.row img`

```css
hr {
  opacity: .5;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-style: inset;
  background: #00adbd;
  border-top: 0.5px dotted #fff;
}

.disabledbutton {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#outeroutside {
  background-image: url("/assets/tile.jpg");
  background-color: #a00f14;
  width: 1300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#outside {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(252, 251, 245, 0.95);
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#welcomemain p {
  width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  height: auto;
}

#welcomemain img {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  color: #2e1f11;
}

#outeroutside a:link {
  color: #996515;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#outeroutside a:hover {
  color: #FFD700;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#outeroutside a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #996515;
}

#outeroutside a:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.row2 a {
  color: #C0C0C0 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.row2 a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #999999;
}

.row2 a:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#navigation img {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.youtube {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60%; // This is the aspect ratio
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.youtube iframe {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

b {
  color: #312112;
}

i {
  color: #b05830;
}

.font {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .spinner {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 10px groove #fdec6d;
  border-right-color: #739968;
  border-bottom-color: #739968;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img:before {
  display: none;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1.colored .info {
  background: #1a4a72;
  background: rgba(26, 74, 114, 0.6);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #333333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px white, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info p {
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .spinner {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ih-item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item,
.ih-item * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ih-item a {
  color: #333;
}

.ih-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ih-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ih-item.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ih-item.circle .img {
  position: relative;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ih-item.circle .img:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle .img img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ih-item.circle .info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .spinner {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 10px solid #ecab18;
  border-right-color: #1ad280;
  border-bottom-color: #1ad280;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .img:before {
  display: none;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1.colored .info {
  background: #1a4a72;
  background: rgba(26, 74, 114, 0.6)
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  height: 110px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 .info p {
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 11px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .spinner {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ih-item.circle.effect1 a:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
  padding: 10px 3px 30px 3px;
  width: 1115px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nonwrap;
  align-content: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: rgba(238, 155, 195, 0.95);
}

.row img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row2 {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px 3px 15px 3px;
  width: 1115px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nonwrap;
  align-content: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: rgba(238, 46, 54, 0.95);
}

.col-sm-6 li {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  max-width: 33.3%;
}

a.effect-shine:hover {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 30%, #000 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 70%);
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
  animation: shine 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 150%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: -50%;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="week1">
            <ul class="row">

              <img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Scroll_Week1.1.png">




              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Gator_Buckles.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>$5 Gator Buckle Sets</h3>
                        <p>Get a selection of 6-piece gator buckle sets for just $5. These opulent adornments are jewel encrusted and waiting to make your belt fancy!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/5-gator-buckle-sets" class="effect-shine">Click here to see all styles! </a></p>
              </li>
              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Liz_CraftPack.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Liz's Craft Pack</h3>
                        <p>Explore the possibilities of leather craft with Liz's craft pack. Bursting at the seams with leather components, this not-so-little pack is only $25!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>

                  <P> <a href="/Lizs-Craft-Pack" class="effect-shine">Get Liz's Craft Pack Here!</a></p>
              </li>
              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Stamping_Tools.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>25% Off Stamping Tools</h3>
                        <p>Transform your veg tan with stamping tools! For this month only, get select stamping tools at an even lower price! Nearly 100 tools are included!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/tools/Tools-Specials-Closeouts-Deals/SALE-Stamping-Tools" class="effect-shine">Click here to view the selection!</a></p>
              </li>

              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_BeltBend_Black.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Black Belt Bends</h3>
                        <p>These Hermann Oak drum dyed belt bends are magnificent and they're on sale! Get them in black or brown. </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/Hermann-Oak-Belt-Bend-Black" class="effect-shine">Get Black Hermann Oak Belt Bend Here!</a></p>
              </li>

              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_BeltBend_Brown.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Brown Belt Bends</h3>
                        <p>These Hermann Oak drum dyed belt bends are magnificent and they're on sale! Get them in black or brown.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/Hermann-Oak-Belt-Bend-Brown" class="effect-shine">Get Brown Hermann Oak Belt Bend Here!</a></p>
              </li>


              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_VegTan_Split_Bundle.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Veg Tan Split Bundle</h3>
                        <p>Our new splitter has left us swimming in veg tan splits! Get this sweet bundle for just $15!</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="target.html" class="effect-shine">Get Your Veg Tan Split Bundle Here!</a></p>
              </li>
              <li class="col-sm-6">

                <!-- normal -->
                <div class="ih-item circle effect1">
                  <a href="#">
                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                    <div class="img"><img src="http://springfieldleather.com/assets/Week1_Jr_LegalPad_Templete.jpg" alt="img"></div>
                    <div class="info">
                      <div class="info-back">
                        <h3>Legal Pad Poly Template</h3>
                        <p>We have finally done it! Poly templates for one of our favorite projects: leather covers! Cover your legal pad in luxury with this template for only $5.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                  <P> <a href="/Polymer-Templates-Junior-Legal-Pad-Cover" class="effect-shine">Get Your Legal Pad Template Here!</a></p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>

          <hr>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am aware that you are not supposed to put non-list items inside of ul's and actually did that as a place holder, but doing it that way actually solved a lot of incidental issues I was having so I left it.

Anyway, thank you! That worked beautifully. I think i had that line in at one point and deleted it because it didn't seem to be making a difference. Thank you!

Comment: @ChaniquaCrook You're welcome.  Glad I could help. :)